# android soundpool не воспроизводит мелодию

Tags: android, аудио

Использую следующий код для воспроизведения звука из ogg файла:

```
public class SoundPoolTest extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {
    SoundPool soundPool;
    int explosionId = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        setContentView(textView);

        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        soundPool = new SoundPool(20, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Sound was loaded with status: " + status);
            }
        });

        try {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = assetManager.openFd("explosion-converted.ogg");
            explosionId = soundPool.load(descriptor, 1);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            textView.setText("Couldn't load sound effect from asset, "
                    + ex.getMessage());
        }
        soundPool.release();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (explosionId != -1) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Sound was successfully loaded: " + explosionId);
                soundPool.play(explosionId, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        soundPool.release();
    }
}
```

И при касании экрана вижу в логах:

> Sound was successfully loaded: 1

но строки `"Sound was loaded with status: "` в логах нет и звук не воспроизводится. Сообщений об ошибках в логах тоже никаких нет. Размер ogg файла - 5Kb. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: `soundPool.release();` в конце `onCreate` явно лишний

Comment: @woesss, точно, благодарю! Очепятка, не заметила) Это и решило проблему)

Comment: Есть ещё проблема: если свернуть-развернуть перестанет играть, так как в `onPause` будет выгружен. Нужно инициализацию перенести в `onResume`. В общем создавать/выгружать в парных lifecycle-методах